# Eclipse jump to closing brace

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, curly-braces

What is the keyboard short cut in Eclipse to jump to the closing brace of a scope?

Comment: As a bonus you can also press ALT + Shift + UP to select  everything between those brackets.

Comment: the above short cut is useful, even though a bit long, which you can still customize yourself ~~

Comment: @RafaelLopes As per [@romaintaz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1637242/446921), you can accomplish the same thing by double clicking. In fact, it seems like `alt + shift + up` is universally equivalent to double clicking at the cursor's location, according to my brief experimentation.

Comment: In the HTML editor `ALT + Shift + UP` keeps expanding the selection as you keep pressing it and `ALT + Shift + DOWN` contracts it. Combine that with `ALT + UP/DOWN` to move the code around = very handy.

Comment: @Muhd, double clicking is not exactly the same as it excludes the braces

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Place the cursor next to an opening *or closing* brace and punch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to find the matching brace. If Eclipse can't find one you'll get a *"No matching bracket found"* message.

***edit:*** as [mentioned by Romaintaz below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637242/1030), you can also get Eclipse to auto-select all of the code between two curly braces simply by double-clicking to the immediate right of a opening brace.

Comment: The same accelerator also works for matching parens () and square brackets [].

Comment: Is there a way to select up to matching brace? Visual Studio does this using Ctrl+Shift+] (Ctrl+] means match brace; Shift means select; so Ctrl+Shift+] means select to matching brace... )

Comment: @AgnelKurian - If you look at @Romaintaz's answer below, you will note "that a double-click to the immediate right of the `{` will select the whole code block..."

Comment: @ninesided - Agnel wants to select from current location to end of block, not the whole; like Shift+End selects from current location to EOL. Btw, I think it's not possible (which matching would you select till? "})]" ), since Ctrl+Shift+P works with all kinds of brackets, while VS only does with braces.

Comment: It looks like this shortcut can help you find matching tags in xml, too.  romaintaz's trick doesn't seem to work there though.

Comment: @ninesided - I am using Ruby DLTK plugin with eclipse kepler in Ruby perspective. In one case of ruby code, this did not work. There was something like - `describe "SomeThingNew" do...etc`. I put applied the trick to this `do`, but landed on some code instead of an `end`. As you might know, do and end are ruby's equivalent of opening and closing braces. Can you please help me to find out why ? Thanks.

Comment: @ninesided In xhtml file how to move to the closing tag from the opened tag of a component?

Comment: For me this only works with JAVA.  When I edit javascript code inside an JSP file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 131):

As the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> has been cited, I just wanted to add a really interesting feature: just double-click to the immediate right of the `{`, and Eclipse will select the whole code block between the opening `{` and corresponding closing `}`. Similarly, double-click to the immediate left of the closing '}' and eclipse will select the block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This also works for square brackets, parentheses, and double quotes.

Comment: I am using Ruby DLTK plugin with eclipse kepler in Ruby perspective. . This does not work for ruby, where do == { and end == }.

Answer (score 80):

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> you can open the "key assist", where you can find all the shortcuts.

Answer (score 20):

On the Macintosh, place the cursor after either the opening or closing curly brace `}` and use the keys: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Answer (score 19):

To select content use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up       arrow</kbd>

To select content up to the next wrapping block press this shortcut again

To go back one step press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +       <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>. This is also a useful shortcut when you need to select content in a complex expression and do not want to miss something.

Answer (score 16):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Before Eclipse Juno you need to place the cursor just beyond an opening or closing brace.

In Juno cursor can be anywhere in the code block.

Comment: The steps to turn this cool feature on: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor-> Bracket highlighting -> Enclosing brackets

Answer (score 11):

I found that if the chosen perspective doesn't match the type of the current file, then "go to matching brace" doesn't work.  However, changing perspectives makes it work again.  So, for example, when I have a PHP file open, but, say, the Java perspective active, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> does nothing.  For the same file with the PHP perspective active, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> does exactly what you'd expect and puts my cursor beside the closing brace relative to the one it started at.