# Eclipse - how to go to matching bracket?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, brackets

How to go to matching bracket in Eclipse IDE (in Text, Java or JavaScript)?

(match opening and closing brackets)

I naturally tried <kbd>Ctrl+}</kbd>, but it is not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse jump to closing brace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289342/eclipse-jump-to-closing-brace)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can see the setting for this in `Preferences > General > Keys` and search for `Go to Matching Bracket`.

On my Mac it is <kbd>Shift+Cmd+P</kbd> (so probably  <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd> on Windows/Linux).

Comment: not working in my eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

Answer (score 15):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> . This may help you getting what you need.