# How to autocomplete curly braces and move cursor into it automatically in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, curly-braces

I am new into Eclipse. I found that when I type `Ctrl + (` it will also generate `)` automatically, and move the cursor into this pair at the same time. After I finish editing coding in the pair, the cursor will jump out the parentheses automatically when typing `Ctrl + )`.

It's very convenient because I don't need to take a long distance movement to operate the arrow keys with my right hand every time. I also found `[]` also has this functionality. Unfortunately, I still don't find any combine-keys with `{}` to perform this functionally. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Which of the many languages supported by Eclipse are you asking about?

Comment: @greg-449 do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look on [Eclipse jump to closing brace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289342/).

Open in Eclipse **Preferences** from menu **Window**.

Navigate on left side to **Java - Editor - Typing**.

There is the option **{Braces}** in the group **Automatically close**. Check this option.

Also in **Preferences** navigate to **General - Keys**.

There is in the list the command **Go to Matching Bracket** with **Editing Java Source** in column **When**. You can redefine the key binding of this command.